# Undefined reference to `xdr_string' with GNU libc 2.31

Tags: gcc, ld, glibc

Should `xdr_string` be part of glibc? I got undefined reference to `xdr_string` with glibc 2.31. I check the symbols and seems all `xdr_*` methods has @GLIBC_2.2.5 suffix.

```sh
% rpm -qf libc.so.6
glibc-2.31-7.30.x86_64
% nm libc.so.6 |grep "\b xdr_"
0000000000126970 T xdr_accepted_reply@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000132850 T xdr_array@GLIBC_2.2.5
00000000001285b0 T xdr_authdes_cred@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000128630 T xdr_authdes_verf@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000124b20 T xdr_authunix_parms@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

It works fine on glibc 2.22

```sh
% rpm -qf libc.so.6
glibc-2.22-114.22.1.x86_64
% nm libc.so.6 |grep "\b xdr_"
00000000001125d0 T xdr_accepted_reply
000000000011d3d0 T xdr_array
0000000000114020 T xdr_authdes_cred
00000000001140b0 T xdr_authdes_verf
00000000001108a0 T xdr_authunix_parms
```

Is it expected for glibc 2.31? How to correctly resolve the reference `xdr_string@GLIBC_2.2.5` ?

I searched around and seems there's some asm directive `__asm__(".symver ...`, but in my case the `xdr_string` is used by a 3rd party lib `libnl` which I'm linking to, I cannot change the lib itself.

```
% g++ main.c libnl.a -ldl -lpthread libmycrypto.so
/usr/x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: libnl.a(nl2.o): in function `xdr_stringUC16':
/bas/src/flat/nl2.c:559: undefined reference to `xdr_string'
/usr/x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /bas/src/flat/nl2.c:566: undefined reference to `xdr_string'
/usr/x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /bas/src/flat/nl2.c:579: undefined reference to `xdr_string'
/usr/x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /bas/src/flat/nl2.c:579: undefined reference to `xdr_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

BTW: A side question, the "-lc" is specified for "ld", how does it resolved to "libc.so.6"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should xdr_string be part of glibc?

`xdr_*` functions are part of SunRPC package, which has been [removed](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/SunRPCRemoval) (after many years of being deprecated).

> A side question, the "-lc" is specified for "ld", how does it resolved to "libc.so.6"?

Find an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10202793/50617).

Comment: Thanks for this info, very useful. I find that my glibc might be built with SunRPC disabled (https://codebrowser.dev/glibc/glibc/sunrpc/xdr.c.html#810) as another machine with same glibc version do have the xdr_ simbols.